# How to implement auto logout in Javascript

Tags: javascript

The below code works for the most part but I am wondering if it's possible to tweak it a bit. If there is no mouse activity for x number of milliseconds, a popup window is displayed saying that you will be logged out. Then,  if / when you click the ok button the script will automatically bring you to the logout file.

However, I would also like to bring the screen to the logout.php file if the ok button is not clicked after x number of milliseconds. Does anyone know how I might do this with the below code?
Thanks

```
// Set timeout variables.
var timoutWarning = 840000; // Display warning in 14 Mins.
var timoutNow = 100000; // Timeout in 15 mins would be 900000.
var logoutUrl = 'logout.php'; // URL to logout page.

var warningTimer;
var timeoutTimer;

// Start timers.
function StartTimers() {
    warningTimer = setTimeout("IdleWarning()", timoutWarning);
    timeoutTimer = setTimeout("IdleTimeout()", timoutNow);
}

// Reset timers.
function ResetTimers() {
    clearTimeout(warningTimer);
    clearTimeout(timeoutTimer);
    StartTimers();
    $("#timeout").dialog('close');
}

// Show idle timeout warning dialog.
function IdleWarning() {
//  $("#timeout").dialog({
    //modal: true
    alert("Warning, your page will redirected to login page. Due to not move your mouse within the page in 15 minutes.");
//});
}

// Logout the user.
function IdleTimeout() {
    window.location = logoutUrl;
}
```

Comment: I hope keyboard activity also resets your timer.

Comment: What if the user turns off javascript?

Comment: @vbudo unrelated answer to OP's question on how to implement it in JS. I suppose he thought about it while/before implementing it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Conceptually, you only need 1 timer running at a time.  One timer that runs for 14 minutes and another that runs for another minute (15 minutes total).  Once the 14 minute timer runs out, kill it and then start the 1 minute timer.  If that one minute timer runs out, log the user out.  If the user presses the "Stay Logged In" button, kill the 1 minute timer and restart the 14 minute timer.  Rinse and repeat.

I changed your code the best I could.  Hope you get the point.

```
// Set timeout variables.
var timoutWarning = 840000; // Display warning in 14 Mins.
var timoutNow = 60000; // Warning has been shown, give the user 1 minute to interact
var logoutUrl = 'logout.php'; // URL to logout page.

var warningTimer;
var timeoutTimer;

// Start warning timer.
function StartWarningTimer() {
    warningTimer = setTimeout("IdleWarning()", timoutWarning);
}

// Reset timers.
function ResetTimeOutTimer() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutTimer);
    StartWarningTimer();
    $("#timeout").dialog('close');
}

// Show idle timeout warning dialog.
function IdleWarning() {
    clearTimeout(warningTimer);
    timeoutTimer = setTimeout("IdleTimeout()", timoutNow);
    $("#timeout").dialog({
        modal: true
    });
    // Add code in the #timeout element to call ResetTimeOutTimer() if
    // the "Stay Logged In" button is clicked
}

// Logout the user.
function IdleTimeout() {
    window.location = logoutUrl;
}
```

Comment: This will not work when multiple tabs are open. because clearTimeout(); does not work across multiple tabs.

Comment: Also timeouts may or may not run in background tabs, depending on how the browser decides to dedicate resources to. In my experience with Chromium browsers

Answer (score 10):

update to @VtoCorleone's answer :

```
var warningTimeout = 840000;
var timoutNow = 60000;
var warningTimerID,timeoutTimerID;

function startTimer() {
    // window.setTimeout returns an Id that can be used to start and stop a timer
    warningTimerID = window.setTimeout(warningInactive, warningTimeout);
}

function warningInactive() {
    window.clearTimeout(warningTimerID);
    timeoutTimerID = window.setTimeout(IdleTimeout, timoutNow);
    $('#modalAutoLogout').modal('show');
}

function resetTimer() {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutTimerID);
    window.clearTimeout(warningTimerID);
    startTimer();
}

// Logout the user.
function IdleTimeout() {
    document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();
}

function setupTimers () {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer, false);
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", resetTimer, false);
    document.addEventListener("keypress", resetTimer, false);
    document.addEventListener("touchmove", resetTimer, false);
    document.addEventListener("onscroll", resetTimer, false);
    startTimer();
}

$(document).on('click','#btnStayLoggedIn',function(){
    resetTimer();
    $('#modalAutoLogout').modal('hide');
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    setupTimers();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to do the same functionality for our project.
Used the following code:-

```
 <script>
   $(document).click(function(){
        if(typeof timeOutObj != "undefined") {
            clearTimeout(timeOutObj);
        }

        timeOutObj = setTimeout(function(){ 
            localStorage.clear();
            window.location = "/";
        }, 1200000);   //will expire after twenty minutes

   });
</script>
```

The above code will set a timer every time we click anywhere on the screen.
In case we don't click it auto-logs out to home screen.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that keeping the mouse on a text field doesn't fire off the timer.

Comment: this will not work when multiple tabs(of your site) are open.

Comment: As far as, my observation goes,  clearTimeout(); does not work across multiple tabs.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
             var IDLE_TIMEOUT = 10; //seconds
                var _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
                document.onclick = function() {
                _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
                };
                document.onmousemove = function() {
                _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
                };
                document.onkeypress = function() {
                _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
                };
                window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime, 1000);

                function CheckIdleTime() {
                _idleSecondsCounter++;
                var oPanel = document.getElementById("SecondsUntilExpire");
                if (oPanel)
                oPanel.innerHTML = (IDLE_TIMEOUT - _idleSecondsCounter) + "";
                if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
                //alert("Time expired!");
                document.location.href = "logout.php";
                }
                }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this code.

```
        var timeoutTimer;
        var expireTime = 1000*60*30;
        function expireSession(){
            clearTimeout(timeoutTimer);
            timeoutTimer = setTimeout("IdleTimeout()", expireTime);
        }
        function IdleTimeout() {
            localStorage.setItem("logoutMessage", true);
            window.location.href="{{url('logout')}}";
        }
        $(document).on('click mousemove scroll', function() {
            expireSession();
        });
        expireSession();
```