# javascript autologout for inactivity for 10 minutes

Tags: javascript, timer

hello all i am writing a code for auto logout for inactivity for about 20 minutes which should interact with keyboard as well as mouse and i have following code which works for most of the function but it is not resetting the timer for mouse movement and keyboard activity.

```
var timoutWarning = 9000; // Display warning in 14 Mins.
var timoutNow = 9000; // Warning has been shown, give the user 1 minute to interact
var logoutUrl = 'logout.php'; // URL to logout page.

var warningTimer;
var timeoutTimer;

// Start warning timer.
function StartWarningTimer() {
    warningTimer = setTimeout("IdleWarning()", timoutWarning);
}

// Reset timers.
function ResetTimeOutTimer() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutTimer);
    StartWarningTimer();
    $("#timeout").hide();
}

// Show idle timeout warning dialog.
function IdleWarning() {
    clearTimeout(warningTimer);
    timeoutTimer = setTimeout("IdleTimeout()", timoutNow);
    $("#timeout").show();
}

// Logout the user.
function IdleTimeout() {
    window.location = logoutUrl;
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
    StartWarningTimer();
});
$('html').mousemove(function() {
    ResetTimeOutTimer();
});
```

i want the code should intract with mouse movement and keyboard press
all kind of help is appreciated please suggest me something

Comment: You may want to have a look at `onmousemove` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmousemove and `onkeypress` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onkeypress

Comment: Please spellcheck your title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript auto logout code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023916/javascript-auto-logout-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, you should not use `setTimeout` this way - inactive tabs [getting slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032429/chrome-timeouts-interval-suspended-in-background-tabs), so there's no guarantee that your code will be executed in 14 minute. The better way to do that is to check repeatedly the elapsed time.

```
var startTime = +new Date();
function checkForWarning () {
    if (+new Date() - startTime > maxInactiveTime) {
        // show warning
    }
}
```

You can track activity this way:

```
$(document)
    .on('click', ResetTimeOutTimer)
    .on('mousemove', ResetTimeOutTimer);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You have to calculate the elapsed time by difference between current time and the moment you start counting. that's the reliable way. And that's what my code does - we remember the moment we started in startTime. Then goes the method (checkForWarning) that checks whether time is out or not. We should call it repeatedly, like this setTimeout(checkForWarning, 1000 * 60)