# Logout automatically after 1 minutes using php

Tags: php

I am creating a simple login page using session and cookie. If the user login on system and if the user don't do anything on the page,it will redirect to login page again after 1 minutes using php
What I have tried so far is attached below.

Login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    $username = $_POST['uname'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];

    if($username == "kobi" && $password == "123"){
        $_SESSION["uname"]=$username;
        setcookie("user", $username, time() + (60)); 
        header('location:welcome.php');        
    }
}
?>
```

welcome.php

```
<?php
    session_start();    
    echo "User Name " .  $_SESSION['uname'] . ".<br>";    
?>
```

Comment: no i solve the problem. this is my new question.

Comment: Logout automatically after 1 minutes using php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript auto logout code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023916/javascript-auto-logout-code)

Comment: Can you set session timeout on server level ? Coookie value can be changes by anyone so not secure

Comment: i don't know how to write i need logout automatically after 1 minutes if the user doesn't do any of the welcome.php

Comment: With php is not posible make this trigger in the same page, you should use a js function

Comment: how to write  js function

Comment: @creativeone2018, check my comment above.

Comment: i put the code js code but it didn't redirect after 1 minutes if the user doesn't do any of the welcome.php

Comment: Should it redirect to loginpage after one minute if user reloads the page? Or do you want it to redirect even if user does not reload the page? This is an important difference.

Comment: if user does not reload the page redirect to loginpage

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should change the setcookie time function.

as your function was

```
setcookie("user", $username, time() + (60));
```

So remove the time second as round brackets

```
setcookie("user", $username, time() + 60);
```

Hopefully this works.

Comment: That's the same!

Comment: sir  i tried above one setcookie("user", $username, time() + 60) after 1 minutes if the user doesn't do any of the welcome.php it didn't redirect to login.php page